# Frasi curiose per imparare la grammatica

Tags: grammar

Nel mio libro di grammatica delle medie, per far capire l'importanza delle virgole, c'era una vignetta che mi è rimasta talmente impressa che me la ricordo ancora oggi, a distanza di decenni.

> *Un tizio al luna park, davanti ad una macchinetta della fortuna, leggeva un biglietto con questa frase:*
>
> LAVORERAI MOLTO POCO GUADAGNERAI
>
> *Il tizio era alquanto perplesso perché, a seconda di dove metteva la virgola, la frase cambiava di significato:*
>
> Lavorerai, molto poco guadagnerai
>
> Lavorerai molto, poco guadagnerai
>
> Lavorerai molto poco, guadagnerai
>
> *e quindi non sapeva se essere contento o triste.*

Mi piacerebbe avere un esempio altrettanto divertente sull'uso degli accenti ed uno sull'uso degli apostrofi. :)

Comment: "Un giorno un re scoprì che un suo vecchio amico era condannato a morte. Mandò un messaggio al secondino con scritto *Liberare mai eseguire la condanna*. Ovviamente il re intendeva *Liberare, mai eseguire la condanna*, ma purtroppo il secondino lesse *Liberare mai, eseguire la condanna*. E fu così che il re imparò l'importanza di scrivere le virgole." (Trascritto dalla memoria da un mio vecchio libro di lettura)

Comment: È una domanda divertente, ma così com'è posta («per l'uso di accenti, apostrofi o altro») è un po' troppo vaga e non ammette una risposta specifica, ma solo esempi potenzialmente infiniti di frasi a doppia lettura...

Comment: @DaG Così può andar bene? Altrimenti si accettano suggerimenti su come modificarla! Mi dispiacerebbe cancellarla del tutto perché mi sembra una cosa simpatica :)

Comment: Quindi la domanda sarebbe: "esistono frasi il cui significato cambia a seconda della posizione dell'accento o dell'apostrofo"?

Comment: @CarLaTeX Normalmente non commenterei, ma visto che è un sito dedicato all'italiano, usiamo *modificare* invece di *editare*... (sì lo so che ormai ha fatto la sua strada fino ai dizionari, ma se non cerchiamo noi di usare le parole più adatte chi lo farà?)

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi Sì, ottimo, modifica pure la mia domanda!

Comment: @DenisNardin Ho rimediato subito!

Comment: È latino, ma la famosa *IBIS REDIBIS NON MORIERIS IN BELLO* va citata. Allora le virgole non esistevano. `;-)`

Comment: @egreg è sempre basata sullo spostamento della virgola (o delle parole stesse, visto che in latino l'ordine non è importante)... la domanda è su frasi ambigue con accenti o apostrofi...
Mi viene in mente:
"La pésca è buona" (sostantivo dal verbo pescare)
"La pèsca è buona" (il frutto del pesco)

Comment: @egreg comunque un tocco di classe, come sempre!

Comment: C'è la famosa filastrocca di Rodari sulla differenza tra Como e comò (http://www.paroledautore.net/filastrocche/italiane/rodari/rodari-como.htm). In generale Rodari era un maestro di questo genere di cose (vedasi il povero 'ane di Firenze etc.)

Comment: @DenisNardin Bella! La tua potrebbe essere già una risposta.

Comment: Altri due esempi non pertinenti, perché si riferiscono ad altre lingue, ma divertenti:   
1) il titolo del libro di Lynne Truss *Eats, Shoots and Leaves* che, a seconda della presenza o meno della virgola, si riferisce a un pistolero o a un panda;   
2) La [storia di come Martino per un punto perse la cappa](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uno_pro_puncto_caruit_Martinus_Asello).

Comment: @DaG  Non conoscevo l'origine di _per un punto Martin perse la cappa_, bella anche questa!

Comment: @DenisNardin: Non c'era qualcosa di Rodari anche su un “lago” e “l'ago”, il che completerebbe la risposta?

Comment: http://www.poesieracconti.it/poesie/a/gianni-rodari/lago-di-garda

Comment: @CarLaTeX, forse ti può interessare anche il fenomeno della [rianalisi](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/rianalisi_(Enciclopedia-dell'Italiano)/), esemplificato dal fatto che “lastrico” viene dal latino volgare **astracum* o **astricum* attraverso l'agglutinazione dell'articolo: “l'astrico”. E così in vari altri casi.

Comment: Chiedi con parsimonia molto riceverai. Zio Paperone.

Answer (score 6):

Non so se siano tanto divertenti, ma queste frasi sull'uso dell'accento appaiono sulla ristampa 2011 della Dodicesima edizione del vocabolario Zingarelli che si può scaricare gratuitamente su Kindle:

> - Cose che càpitano al capitàno: ha perso ancóra l’àncora.
> - Prìncipi senza princìpi: amano la pésca e non la pèsca.

Comment: Ottimo, @Charo, mi pare che non ci fosse ancora una risposta sugli accenti!

Answer (score 4):

Una delle [microtragedie di Achille Campanile](http://linfoart.blogspot.it/2013/05/4497-le-microtragedie-di-campanile-1.html)

**Non sappiamo**

Personaggi:
DINORAH, cantante
CORA, padrona di casa
NORA, pianista che non parla

In un salotto, durante un trattenimento musicale. All’alzarsi del sipario, Cora ha pregato Dinorah di cantare qualche cosa.

DINORAH
Canterei volentieri la canzone intitolata “Signora”, ma temo che Nora, che dovrebbe accompagnarmi al piano, non la conosca. Qui non sapete se la conosce?

CORA
Parola di Cora, signora Dinorah: sinora di Nora s’ignora se ignora “Signora”.

(sipario)

Answer (score 3):

Accetta l'accetta e lascia l'ascia.

Da una delle “tragedie in due battute” di Achille Campanile: QUANDO LUCIO LASCIA L'ASCIA 
Personaggi: LUCIO LICIO

Lucio ha due asce, una scabra e una, invece, liscia. Il suo amico Licio gli chiede quest'ultima in prestito, pregandolo di lasciargliela sulla porta di casa. Licio, a sua volta, ha due porte, anch'esse una scabra e una liscia, perciò chiede all'amico a quale delle due desidera gli sia lasciato l'oggetto.
L'altro glielo dice e in più lo prega di dargli, in quella circostanza, una lustratina alla porta. Indi brindano. Ma lasciamo ai due la parola. 
LICIO: Lucio, lascia l'ascia all'uscio. 
LUCIO: L'ascia scabra o l'ascia liscia? 
LICIO: Lascia all'uscio l'ascia liscia. 
LUCIO: Licio, lascio l'ascia liscia all'uscio liscio? 
LICIO: Lucio, esci e lascia l'ascia liscia all'uscio liscio, liscia l'uscio e mesci! (Sipario)

Comment: Per completezza, la variante più illustre è una delle “tragedie in due battute” di Achille Campanile:  

QUANDO LUCIO LASCIA L'ASCIA
Personaggi:
LUCIO
LICIO

Lucio ha due asce, una scabra e una, invece, liscia. Il suo amico Licio gli chiede quest'ultima in prestito, pregandolo di lasciargliela sulla porta di casa. Licio, a sua volta, ha due porte, anch'esse una scabra e una liscia, perciò chiede all'amico a quale delle due desidera gli sia lasciato l'oggetto. [segue]

Comment: L'altro glielo dice e in più lo prega di dargli, in quella circostanza, una lustratina alla porta. Indi brindano. Ma lasciamo ai due la parola.

LICIO: Lucio, lascia l'ascia all'uscio.
LUCIO: L'ascia scabra o l'ascia liscia?
LICIO: Lascia all'uscio l'ascia liscia.
LUCIO: Licio, lascio l'ascia liscia all'uscio liscio?
LICIO: Lucio, esci e lascia l'ascia liscia all'uscio liscio, liscia l'uscio e mesci!

(Sipario)

Comment: wow grazie DaG! non sapevo da dove venisse la frase!

Comment: @Dru Potresti completare la risposta, arricchendola con il testo completo

Comment: Confermo, @Dru, inserisci pure: sei stato tu a farmela tornare in mente.

Comment: Modificato :) su https://it.wikiquote.org/wiki/Achille_Campanile ce ne sono delle altre altrettanto divertenti!

Answer (score 1):

Io dalle elementari conoscevo anche:

- Qui, quo, qua l'accento non ci va.
- Are, ere, ire, la mutina (la lettera h) va a dormire.